# pg_dump compression format

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

pg_dump `compress` option has the following [description](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html):

> Specify the compression level to use. Zero means no compression. For the custom archive format, this specifies compression of individual table-data segments, and the default is to compress at a moderate level. For plain text output, setting a nonzero compression level causes the entire output file to be compressed, as though it had been fed through gzip; but the default is not to compress. The tar archive format currently does not support compression at all.

Does it mean that the archive will have gzip format?

Comment: I believe it's zlib under the covers, but that doesn't mean you can run gunzip against it.

Answer (score 3):

The GZIP File Format has a [header](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer) starting with the bytes 0x1f, 0x8b.

On the other hand, a file produced by `pg_dump` custom archive format (option `-Fc`) starts with the letters P,G,D,M,P, which is enough to conclude that it's not in the gzip format.

Answer (score 0):

The `-Fc` format is compressed; [per the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html):

> This format is also compressed by default.

Under the `--compress` section, it states the compression level for custom-formatted dumps:

> For the custom archive format, this specifies compression of individual table-data segments, and the default is to compress at a moderate level.